# Creating embeds for a bot gives error 50035

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord.js, javascript-objects

I am creating a bot with javascript and it is supposed to create an embed for each respective element but it doesn't work

I expected it to create an embed for each element but it gives me error 50035

```js
const {
  SlashCommandBuilder,
  EmbedBuilder
} = require('discord.js');

const createEmbed = async(filteredFighters) => {
  filteredFighters.forEach(filteredFighters => {
    const exampleEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setTitle(filteredFighters.Nickname)
      .addFields({
          name: 'PELEA PRINCIPAL',
          value: `${filteredFighters.FirstName}`
        }, {
          name: 'PELEA SECUNDARIA',
          value: `${filteredFighters.LastName}`
        },

      );
    return exampleEmbed;
  });
};
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=error+50035+discord+embed+site:stackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: What do you expect `createEmbed` to return? Because at the moment there is no `return` statement there.